# Get touch event easily when scrolling the scrollView in React Native Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview

React-native Android, when touchable component is put, such as TouchableOpacity in a scrollView/listView, it's very easy to get touch event when the scrollView/listView is scrolling. In react-native iOS, everything is fine. But in React Native Android, it's very annoying.

It's strange, no one ask this question before.

Has anyone seen this issue?

`<ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
          automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
          style={styles.listView}
 />`

`renderRow(rowData:rankRecord, sectionID:number, rowID:number) {
    return(
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={{height:70}}
        onPress={() => this.goToProfile(rowData.inner_id)}>
        <RankCell rowData={rowData}/>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }`

Comment: could you please post your code?

Comment: @SusylGhimire done

Comment: you better wrap your row component inside view and better put touchablehighlight inside view. So, that your row object will rendered as view component and when you click only your component will behave as touchable component. <View><TouchableHighlight><TouchableHighlight></View>

Comment: Are you by chance using nested ScrollViews? See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#nestedscrollenabled